# Angular Form submit getting as object instead of value

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating basic angular form and `onsubmit` trying to retrieve the form value, but my case instead of getting value I am getting value as object.

**Note:** copied the code with some example.

can you please let me know why i am getting object instead of value?

Please find my below code:

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>  User Data </h2>
    <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ngModel>
      </div>    
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

component:

```
onSubmit(value: any) {
  console.log("Form Value : " + value);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the output of console.log?

Comment: `userForm.value` is an object.
It contains name and email controls in it.
you need to check field value individually like `value.name` and `value.email` in your onSubmit method

Comment: You are getting an object because your form contains keys. Each key has a value and therefore it is returned as an object.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/forms take a look at the summary in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `userForm.value` contains two values which are `name` and `email`.

So when you do `console.log(userForm.value);`, it will return something like this:

```
{
  name: 'Surjeet',
  email: 'suri@yopmail.com'
}
```

To access the particular value you can do:

1. `userForm.value.name` => It will return **'Surjeet'**
2. `userForm.value.email` => It will return **'suri@yopmail.com'**

**So what you can do now:**

```
Two things you can do in your case:
```

**First one**: (get the value by its property)

```
onSubmit(value: any) {
  //get the value by its property
  console.log("Name: " + value.name);
  console.log("Email: " + value.email);
}
```

**Second one**: (pass only those value which you need)

*//(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value.name)"*

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>  User Data </h2>
    <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value.name)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ngModel>
      </div>    
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value has to be an object. The form contains multiple elements , hence has multiple values.

Try this:

```
     onSubmit(value: any) {
        console.log("Form Value : ",value);
        console.log(value.name);
        console.log(value.email);
     }
```

Comment: It appeared undefined to me, i forgot to put ngModel in form

Answer (score 0):

Your input field should be something like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" formControlName="name">
```

and then in submit function get it's value like

```
onSubmit(post){
   console.log(post.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--> in HTML file
<div class="container">
    <h2>  User Data </h2>
    <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value.name,userForm.value.email)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ngModel>
      </div>    
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>


--> in TS file
onSubmit(name:any, email:any) {
        console.log('Name = ' + name);
        console.log('Email = ' + email);
     }


--> By this code you can get specific value in form either by button triggering (should mention required properties to submit and also in receiving method) or by entire form submit.
```